# CLI: set website

Tags: cli, coding, shell

I'm trying CLI coding. I just tried to get all Users, want to load them and list data or do some actions.

```
<?php

require_once 'abstract.php';

class Shell_List extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {
    public function run() {
        $users = Mage::getModel('customer/customer') -> getCollection() -> getData();
        foreach ($users as $u) {
            $user = mage::getModel('customer/customer') -> loadByEmail($email =  $u['email']);
            echo $email, ' ', $user -> getName(), "\n";
        }
    }
}

$shell = new Shell_List();
$shell -> run();
```

Well, the loadByEmail() methods throws an exception with the message

```
Customer website ID must be specified when using the website scope
```

That's logical, a user identified email can exist in more websites.
How do I set the website, and maybe, list all users of the website?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you can just do this:

```
    $users = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')-> setWebsiteId(1)->getCollection() -> getData();
```

Replace 1 with your store code ID in setWebsiteId() to change the store. I'm away from my system so I didn't get a chance to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how it should work without having to set the website ID manually:

```
$email = “someone@somedomain.com”;
$customer = Mage::getModel(“customer/customer”);
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);
```

On another note, you could simply get the website_id via the store_id which is saved in the customer data (in your case it would be u['store_id']):

```
$storeId = u['store_id'];
$website_id = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
```

Comment: In a CLI script using shell/abstract.php, Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() will return 0.

Comment: But it's helpful for frontend code, thank you :)